# ios increasing uitextview height doesn't adjust layout

Tags: ios, height, uitextview

Programmatically, I have created my textview , which is a subview inside of a scrollview. There are other subviews on the bottom of the textview.

The desired functionality is that when the content size height of the textview increases (from typing, or pasting in text, or programmatically setting the text), the textview should expand, and the views that are underneath it should push down too.

This is currently how Twitter's posting feature works. Image previews are below the text and is pushed down as the textview expands, this is all inside of a scrollview.

Unfortunately for me, This doesn't happen. Text just disappears underneath them.

I have a `textViewDidChange` method from the UITextView delegate, and I try to use code from other stackoverflow solutions intended to readjust the size of the textView. There must be some combination of setting the frame and height and using`sizeToFit` and `setNeedsLayout` that must work, but so far none of them work for me. Even re-adding the constraints from my layout elements, in the `textViewDidChange` method have zero affect on the layout.

How do I get the textView to expand downward when its content amount changes, and have all the other views seamlessly move downward?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this without knowing how your constraints are setup for the other controls.  Typically, if they have no vertical relationship with your textView, they would not adjust to changes in the textView's size.  If you are using Interface builder, you could visually test the relationships by playing with the height constraint of your textView.

Comment: this gives me a hint, I'll get back to you. I am using als_shorthand library most of the time for my programmatic layouts, but I can use plain VFL to more directly tie things together